React App not rendering anything after '/'
I created an app using create-react-app and I have nested routes in my App.js. The Public component displays but nothing else does , such as /login or /home.
I added the /login just to test out a simple page, because Dash Layout is also nesting other elements but it does not render. I don't think it is a css issue because when I inspect the page there is nothing inside the [[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/itfVQp7j.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/2HNl7OM6.png)

You should NOT post images of code, data, error messages. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should structure your code in a different way.
In index.js:
// ...

root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);

You really don't need to use two different Routes component (you are creating a Routes component with the App inside and then the App component has a Routes component too).

The problem was I was missing the astrisk after the '/' in the path in the index.js file:
<React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>


Have you tried the solution I posted? I don’t think that this would be the right way to achieve your result…
